# How do you return a single value from a scope on a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do I return a single record from this scope? I tried both ways.

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription

  scope :current, -> do  
    # where(paid: nil).order(:created_at).last
    where(paid: nil).order(created_at: :desc).limit(1).first
  end
```

The first way correctly adds `order by ... desc limit 1`, but then it executes another query without the where condition!

> irb(main):004:0> s.invoices.current
>       Invoice Load (22.0ms)  SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."subscription_id" = $1 AND **"invoices"."paid" IS NULL** ORDER BY "invoices"."created_at" **DESC LIMIT $2**  [["subscription_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>       Invoice Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."subscription_id" = $1  [["subscription_id", 16]]
>   => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Invoice id: 8, subscription_id: 16, user_id: 21, **paid: "2018-03-15"**, created_at: "2018-03-14 22:42:48">]>

The second way also does another query, obliterating the correct results.

> irb(main):007:0> s.invoices.current
>   
>       Invoice Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."subscription_id" = $1 AND "invoices"."paid" IS NULL
>   ORDER BY "invoices"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["subscription_id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>   
>       Invoice Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."subscription_id" = $1  [["subscription_id", 16]]
>   
>   => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Invoice id: 8, subscription_id: 16, user_id: 21, **paid: "2018-03-15"**, created_at: "2018-03-14 22:42:48">]>

Also, how do I get just the record, not an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`?

Ruby 5.0.6

Comment: Hmm. I believe, scope implies dataset. Why won't you using self method for model?

Comment: Have you tried `where(paid: nil).order(created_at: :desc).first`?

Comment: @jvillian Same results. Two queries. Loads a relation with a non-null invoice.

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov Because I'm using a relation, not the model class. `@subscription.invoices` is `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` class, not `Invoice` class. I hadn't thought about how Rails does the magic to allow scopes to work on relations. OK I just tried `def self.current ...` and it actually worked, and also returned a single value `Invoice` class! How?

Comment: By definition, `scope` always returns a relation. Some people find it a plus. You just experienced one of the places where it is not. Personally, I don't use scopes. (Thus, the example I provided as an answer.) Some people think I'm insane. They may be correct.

Comment: @jvillian OK, but why is scope failing? If it does the 1st query correctly, maybe it just wraps the results into an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`. But why does it do the 2nd query? And leave off the where clause? If I run `s.invoices.current.first` using the code in the question, then it  does return the 1st `Invoice` result in the `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` (which happens to be an incorrect result), but is not surprising.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I don't know why. Like I said, I never use scopes and so I never have to ponder these questions and instead I can spend my time coding. Once in a great while, the rails magic is just a little to, well, magical for my tastes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the scope with

```
  def self.current
    where(paid: nil).order(:created_at).last
  end
```

And it worked. However I don't know why, as this method is in `Invoice` class, while the relation is `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` class. I wish I knew why it works. And I wish I knew why scope didn't work and performed two queries.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription 

  class << self 

    def for_subscription(subscription)
      where(subscription: subscription)
    end

    def unpaid
      where(paid: nil)
    end

    def newest
      order(created_at: :desc).first 
    end

  end

end
```

Which, if you have an instance of `Subscription` called `@subscription` you could use like:

```
Invoice.unpaid.for_subscription(@subscription).newest
```

I believe that should fire only one query and should return an `invoice` instance.

Comment: That's not a very Rails way to do it. Invoice is a relation of Subscription. You should be able to start with `@subscription` and find the desired relation, not use `@subscription` as a parameter to a static method. I guess it's a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: Yeah, actually, `@subscription.invoices.unpaid.newest` is better. Or, consolidate `.unpaid.newest` into `.current` (as you did), that that's cool, too. I'm not sure what a `static method` is or how `very Rails way` is defined, but it's all good.